# How to show staged version of a file?

Tags: git

The following command allows one to see how the file bar is in the changeset foo:

```
$ git show foo:bar
baz
$
```

Now instead of the changeset foo, I want to see bar as it looks in the staging area. Is it possible to do that?

Note: I do want the content of the file, not some diff.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just omit any commit identifier before the `:`

```
git show :bar
```

and you can also give the [stage number](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_true_merge) as `:n:` up front, 0 = ready, 1 = 
base, 2 = ours, 3 = theirs

```
git show :1:bar       # base content
```